# Receive webhook or other kind of ping from Sanity when a document is published?

Tags: webhooks, sanity, headless-cms

I have a backend that stores data in Sanity.io, and I would like to configure Sanity to ping my app when a document is published, so that I can clear any cached data. This way I can greatly reduce traffic between my app and Sanity. Possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you looked at the webhooks documentation?  https://www.sanity.io/docs/webhooks